# Proj4js can't handle 90/180degree transformations from 4326

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

So if you try to do a transform like this

```
Proj4js.transform( new Proj4js.Proj( 'EPSG:4326' ), 
                   new Proj4js.Proj( 'EPSG:3857' ), 
                   new Proj4js.Point( -180, -90 ) );
```

You will get: `{ x: -Math.PI, y: -Math.PI / 2 }`

So the issue is obvious, you can't reproject the corners of 4326 to 3857.  However, Proj4js does not notify you in anyway that a math error is occurring.

Is there a general solution to these sort of reprojection problems?

So far, I'm thinking about checking for `Point / ( Math.PI / 2 ) % 0` to see if division of PI is being returned then bringing the points closer to 0 so the transformation can be resolved.